# need to know how i can access performance counters of IIS server thru code

Tags: c#, iis

IIS server has many performance counters. how can i pull off these values dynamically thru C# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other performance counters I guess, via *PerformanceCounter* class.

Comment: so you are saying that it is the same as fetching _usual_ performance counters ? Also on the same lines could you please tell me how i could gather various types of counters. Because the way i know is where i supply the category myself and then i collect the data

Comment: @RUYZAKI Yes, they are. Also I'd advise you to use [ASP.NET counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx)  instead of IIS counters if possible. I think the only way to gather data from counters via _PerformanceCounter_ is one by one by providing a category name and a counter name for each counter.